# Retrieve Value from JSON using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am new with json and ajax. I would to ask for assistance on how to Retrieve JSON value using AJAX.

Here is my json file named as list.js

```
{
     "loginid" : "Wafiqa",
     "password": "123"
}
```

and here is my html fille named as ajaxTest.html

```
<body>
     <p> Username: </p>
     <div id="uname"></div>
     <p> Password: </p>
     <div id="pword"></div>
</body>
```

What I want to do is the value from username in json file will be displayed at uname div and the password will display at pword div. How can I do that?

Comment: Format code by indenting it with 4 extra spaces. The backtick ( ` ) is for inline code.

Comment: I'm so sorry I don't understand how to format it

Comment: [formatting guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: And what is the problem? Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: I just don't understand how to display the data using Ajax?

Comment: Ajax is for **getting** the data, not for displaying it. Did you read the tutorials at http://learn.jquery.com at all? They should contain everything you need to know for this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a local file. You will need the json file to be served from a server. You can run your code form a web server.

You can use the [jquery#getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function for this.

For sample, in your html head section have

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <style>
  img {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="images"></div>
 
<script>
(function() {
  $.getJSON( 'http://date.jsontest.com/', {
    format: "json"
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
     alert(data.date);
  });
})();
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had installed tomcat in my pc

Comment: Can you give me an example..  I just don't understand it

Comment: what is the use of div id ="images"?

Comment: $.getJSON() uses ajax inside. jquery wraps xmlhttprequest, makes it easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're just starting to learn JavaScript, it would be easier for you to just put your JSON data in a variable.

```
var jsonData = {
  "loginid" : "Wafiqa",
  "password": "123"
};
```

and then you insert it in the DOM with something like

```
document.getElementById(uname).innerHTML = jsonData.loginid;
document.getElementById(pword).innerHTML = jsonData.password;
```

If you want to use the json in another file you should serve it as a static asset or use some server-side code to render it.

Comment: But..how can I use ajax?